# Local structure of rational varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, open-problems

I've been asked this question by a colleague who's not an algebraic geometer; we both feel that the answer should be "no", but I don't have a clue how to prove it.
Here's the question:
let $X$ be a smooth rational variety (over the complex numbers, say). Is it true that every point of $X$ has a Zariski open neighbourhood that is isomorphic to an open subset of ${\mathbb P}^n$?

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't this true by definition? 

Comment: Qiaochu: _every_ point. (I almost asked the same question, by the way.)

Comment: I have discussed this over the years with several people.  It is expected to be false, but it is open.

Comment: Trivial in dimension 1. True in dimension 2 because the minimal models have this property and blow-ups preserve it. Is it true in dimension 3?

Comment: Jason, thank you, this puts my question in perspective.

Comment: I remember discussing this with Joe Harris many years ago. The problem seems to have been around for a while.

Comment: In dimension 2 the result is true and is in fact stronger: we can assume that the open neighbourhood is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^2$. Do you have a counterexample in dimension $3$ of this?

By the way, I would have thought that the answer to your question (not the stronger one) should be "yes", but as many people think the converse, I am now confused. If a point admits no such neighbourhood, it implies that every birational maps $X\to \mathbb{P}^n$ is either not defined at $x$ or contracts something through $x$. Do you have some candidate for $x$ and $X$?

Answer (score 14):

Some partial results related to this open problem can be found in the very recent preprint by F. Bogomolov and C. Böhning *On uniformly rational varieties*, see [arXiv:1307.0102](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.0102).

According to the authors (see the Introduction) this question was first raised by M. Gromov in his paper

*Oka's principle for holomorphic sections of elliptic bundles*, Journal of the American Mathematical Society **2**, Vol. 4 (1989).

Comment: Grazie Francesco!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a preprint of Ilya Karzhemanov constructing counterexamples in dimensions $n\geq 4$:

http://research.ipmu.jp/ipmu/sysimg/ipmu/1588.pdf