# Algebraic atlas on smooth manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, smooth-manifolds

A real/complex rational atlas on a smooth closed manifold $M$ is an atlas with charts homeomorphic to Euclidean open sets in $\Bbb{R}^n$/$\Bbb{C}^n$ covering $M$ and real/complex rational transition maps. A real/complex rational structure is a maximal collection of compatible mentioned real/complex atlases. Two rational structures are called isomorphic if there is a topological automorphism $\sigma$ of $M$ such that each coordinate representation of $\sigma$ under a rational chart pair (from each structure) is rational. The existence of a rational structure does not imply being algebraic because every complex torus admits one (the transition maps are translations, thus polynomial), so I want to ask about how rigid these structures are.

**Q$1$**: Are there topological invariants classifying whether a smooth manifold admits a real/complex rational structure? Or on the contrary every smooth manifold admits one?

**Q$2$**: Obviously a real/complex rational structure belongs to a smooth/holomorphic structure. Consider the converse problem: what is the moduli space of real/complex rational structures compatible with the smooth/holomorphic structure on $M$? Specifically, **is it true that the number of complex rational structures belonging to the holomorphic structure of $M$ is at most $1$?** Counterexamples are welcome.

**Q$3$**: A [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317125/defining-algebraic-manifold-without-referring-to-schemes) exists on this website, and the first answer gives a sheaf-sense definition of rational structures. However its conclusion -- the algebraic structure of $\Bbb{C}^n$ can be pullbacked onto $M$ -- seems to contradict my complex torus example. I hope someone can help.

Comment: It seems a strong condition that each chart have image homeomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$, and not just to a Zariski open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$. Why do you want that?

Comment: Zerox, you probably want to have charts being open subsets of $\mathbf{K}^n$ (in the Euclidean topology). Otherwise tori $\mathbf{K}^n/\Lambda$ would have no charts as desired, and you would also miss most affine/projective manifolds.

Comment: @YCor You are right. I changed my description.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answers to your question in the case $n=1$ are well-known.  In higher dimensions, the answers are less complete, but something is known.

For example, in the real case when $n=1$, there is only one smooth, connected compact $1$-manifold, the circle, and, for each natural number $k\ge1$, there is a rational structure $\mathcal{R}_k$, which is the rational structure induced on the $k$-fold connected cover of $\mathbb{RP}^1\simeq S^1$ (which is smoothly diffeomorphic to $S^1$, of course).  Two rational structures $\mathcal{R}_i$ and $\mathcal{R}_j$ on the circle are isomorphic if and only if $i=j$, and every rational structure on the circle is isomorphic to some $\mathcal{R}_i$.

Meanwhile, in the complex case when $n=1$, specifying a rational structure on a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ (i.e., a topological surface of genus $g$ with a fixed underlying holomorphic structure) is easily seen to be equivalent to specifying a *projective structure* on the surface.  For $g>1$, it is known that the moduli of projective structures on a given compact Riemann surface is equivalent to the moduli of quadratic holomorphic differentials, a complex vector space of dimension $3g{-}3$.   For example, see R. C. Gunning's *On uniformization of complex manifolds: The role of connections*.  In particular, these provide counterexamples sought by the OP.

In higher dimensions the situation is more complicated because the pseudogroup of rational maps with a rational inverse, i.e., the so-called *birational pseudogroup*, in either $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$ is not well-understood when $n>1$.

However, when $n=2$, the question of when a given compact complex surface has a rational structure is well-understood since we have a classification of compact complex surfaces, by the work of Kodaira.  Not all such surfaces have a rational structure; for example, a K3 surface does not.

Comment: For the classification of holomorphic projective connections on complex surfaces, see Bruno Klingler, *Structures affines et projectives sur les surfaces complexes*, Ann. Inst. Fourier
(Grenoble) 48 (1998), no. 2, 441–477. MR MR1625606 (99c:32038). But these are not the same as rational structures, since the birational automorphisms of the complex affine plane are more complicated.

Comment: Are there results about the well-undertood case of real $2$-manifolds and geometrizable real $3$-manifolds?

Comment: Every primary Kodaira surface admits infinitely many holomorphic rational structures not derived from any projective connection:  McKay, Benjamin *Exotic geometric structures on Kodaira surfaces*. Indiana Univ. Math. J. 62 (2013), no. 2, 643–670.

Comment: @Zerox:  Any connected compact real smooth 2-manifold has a metric of constant curvature $K$, so it has an atlas whose transition maps are isometries between contractible open sets in the simply-connected surface of constant curvature $K$.  Since these latter spaces can be presented in such a way that their isometries are rational maps, every compact real smooth 2-manifold has at least one rational structure. I'm not aware of any classification up to rational equivalence of such real rational structures on 2-manifolds, though. The case of geometrizable 3-manifolds is probably similar.